# I want to fetch total number of likes against each post data using ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to fetch total number of likes on each post using ajax and PHP.

Here is my `ajax.php` file

```
<?php
include_once "../config.php";

 $user_id=$_POST["user_id"];
 $sale_phone_id=$_POST["sale_phone_id"];

$query2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT count(id) as total_likes FROM likes where status='1' AND sale_phones_id='$sale_phone_id'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
echo $row["total_likes"];
?>
```

Here is my JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){

                      var user_id=1;
                      var sale_phone_id=document.getElementById('demo_demo').getAttribute('data-value');
                      //var message=$("#message").val();

                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"ajax.php",
                          data:"user_id="+user_id+"&sale_phone_id="+sale_phone_id,
                          success:function(data){

                            $("#thumbs_up").html(data);
                          }

                      });
            });
   </script>
```

The above mentioned code is only returning me the data of only first post. I want to show the number of likes against all posts.

Comment: Where is the `select` query ?

Comment: I just updated the ajax.php, Sorry I posted the wrong ajax.php file first time.

Comment: Is your query is valid ? Do you want to consider both the specified columns ?

Comment: Yes it is a valid query and I only want the records of those posts who's status =1

Comment: Then remove `AND sale_phones_id='$sale_phone_id'` from query

Comment: OK I get your point, nice suggestion. But still the problem will exist I guess.

Comment: Try it out...Let me know...

Comment: Well I just tried and its not working.
Let me tell you the whole scenario.

Comment: I have multiple posts against which I had to show the counts of likes against each post data.
So I think I had to pass the the foreign key "sale_phones_id" somewhere.

Comment: Try the same query in `mySql` and see the results ...

Comment: well it is now counting all the rows and showing against first post only,

Comment: Your putting all the results into #thumbs_up which is an ID. Which suggests it only exists in one place in the page. 
Also you should escape the variables you are passing into SQL. Especially since Mysqli is very dangerous.

Comment: So could you please suggest that what should I use rather than and ID. And how?

Comment: I would suggest you have a class on each item you wish to put results against. Then change your code to do something like this $('.classname').each( then put your function here). Then in the success section of the ajax I would use $(this) to reference the item. This will cause multiple ajaxes for each item. There are more elegant ways to do this, where you get all the results in 1 hit. Then use the success function to draw them into the correct places.

Comment: Nice suggestion about using class. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are getting only 1 record because you are sending just 1 `sale_phone_id` and your code is useful in a particular case where you need to find out the number of likes for a particular post.

From my understanding of your question, you need to count the number of likes on each and every sale phone. So have to put a join in your
query (assuming **sales_phone** as your other table name); the query given below can fulfill your requirement

```
SELECT *, count(t2.id) as total_likes
FROM sale_phones t1 LEFT JOIN likes t2
ON t2.sale_phones_id=sale_phones_id
WHERE status='1' AND sale_phones_id='$sale_phone_id'
```

This way you will get all the `sales_phones` along with their number of likes.

Now once you get this result in JSON format (in response from your ajax call) the jquery logic is another question.
Well it can be achieved in multiple ways.
The simplest will be to use the **id** attribute with a prefix.
Where looping through the `sale_phones` and creating posts you can assign each post a data `id` like

```
<?php foreach($sale_phones as $sp): ?>
    <div id="sp_<?php echo $sp->id; ?>" >
       <?php echo $sp->phone_name;?>
       <span class="likes"></span>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and in your jquery ajax request function

```
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"ajax.php",
    success:function(data){
       // assuming that your data is returning in JSON format
       var response = JSON.parse(data);
       $('#sp_'+response.sales_phone_id).children('.likes').text(response.total_likes);
    }
 });
```

That's just a rough sketch to achieve what you need. Let me know if i can help out further.

By the way never send `user_id` from client side, it's highly insecure. User can change the ID by inspecting element or another way and will be able to see any user's records in response. Solution is to keep `user_id` in the session and take it from there whenever you need it in your PHP code instead of sending it from client side.

Answer (score 0):

You're only fetching one row, you'll need to fetch all of them:

```
while (false != $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2))
    echo $row["total_likes"];
```

you'll also need some way to seperate the values obviously...